# Merge on columns with multiple values

Tags: r, merge, apply, bioinformatics

I have a data frame, `cluster`, and one of the columns, `cluster$Genes`, looks like this:

```
ENSG00000134684
ENSG00000188846, ENSG00000181163, ENSG00000114391
ENSG00000134684, ENSG00000175390
ENSG00000134684
ENSG00000134684, ENSG00000175390
...
```

The number of elements in each row in the column is arbitrary. I also have another data frame, `expression`, that looks like this:

```
ENSGID           a       b
ENSG00000134684  1       3
ENSG00000175390  2       0
ENSG00000000419  131.23  108.73
ENSG00000000457  7.11    8.68
ENSG00000000460  15.70   6.59
ENSG00000000938  0       0
ENSG00000000971  0.03    0.07
ENSG00000001036  59.22   58.3
...
```

... and has around 20000 rows. What I want to do, is this:

1. For all the elements in each row in the `cluster$Genes`, find the corresponding `a` and `b` values
2. Calculate the min, max and mean values of `a` and `b` (separately) for each row in `cluster$Genes`
3. Create six new columns in the `cluster` data frame and fill them with the `(min.a, max.a, mean.a, min.b, max.b, mean.b)` values

I've tried to find some way of doing this, but it's not going well. While googling for help I thought I might use some kind of `apply`, and I got some code going. I think it's mostly gibberish and totally nonfunctional, and I'm kind of stuck. This is what I got:

```
exp.lookup = function(genes) {
  genes.split = strsplit(genes, ', ')
  exp.hct = list()
  exp.hke = list()
  for ( gene in genes.split ) {
    exp.hct = c(exp.hct, merge(gene, means$hct, all.x=TRUE))
    exp.hke = c(exp.hke, merge(gene, means$hke, all.x=TRUE))
    return(c(exp.hct, exp.hke))
  }
}

apply(cluster['Genes'], 1, FUN=exp.lookup)
```

Anybody got any better ideas, that might actually work?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example on how to do that. You can share data using `dput` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recreating initial data:

```
library(data.table)

cluster<- as.data.table(list(Genes = c("ENSG00000134684",
                                       "ENSG00000188846, ENSG00000181163, ENSG00000114391", 
                                       "ENSG00000134684, ENSG00000175390", 
                                       "ENSG00000134684", 
                                       "ENSG00000134684, ENSG00000175390")))

expression<- as.data.table(list(ENSGID = c("ENSG00000134684", "ENSG00000175390",
                                           "ENSG00000000419", "ENSG00000000457",
                                           "ENSG00000000460", "ENSG00000000938",
                                           "ENSG00000000971", "ENSG00000001036"),
                                a = c(1,2,131.23,7.11,15.70, 0, 0.03, 59.22),
                                b = c(3,0,108.73,8.68,6.59,0,0.07,58.3)))
setkey(cluster, Genes)
setkey(expression, ENSGID)
```

Solution:

```
library(data.table)

result<- function() {
  colnames<- c("min.a", "max.a", "mean.a", "min.b", "max.b", "mean.b")
  # 1. "(colnames)" is parenthesized to insure we are adding new columns from
  # colnames variable by reference and evaluates to character vector with 
  # new columns names
  # 2. ":=" is for adding new columns to existing data.table by reference
  # 3. "count(Genes)" calls count() function over "Genes" column, but as long
  # as we are using grouping "by = Genes", count() works with each row turn
  # by turn. And each row is a character vector.
  cluster[,(colnames):=count(Genes), by = Genes]
}

# get Genes row
count<- function(charvector) {
  ENSGIDc<- strsplit(charvector, ", ")
  # 4. subsetting "expression" data.table rows by splitted "Genes" character 
  # vector named "ENSGIDc"...
  # 5. ... and then calculating column's maxes, mins and means
  expression[ENSGIDc, .(min(a, na.rm = T), max(a, na.rm = T),
                        mean(a, na.rm = T), min(b, na.rm = T), 
                        max(b, na.rm = T), mean(b, na.rm = T))]
  # 6. at this point we are returning resulting 1 row 6 columns data.table     
  # back to calling function, where it's added to "cluster" data.table
}

suppressWarnings(result())
```

Comment: That works wonderfully, thanks a lot! I don't really understand all the details of the code, though... I don't understand the second lines of either function; could you explain, please? It would be nice to not only have working code, but knowing how it functions as well ;-)

Comment: Sure! You might want to start with introduction to data.table: https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro-vignette.html  to get familiar with base syntax. Data Camp's data.table cheat sheet: http://blog.datacamp.com/data-table-cheat-sheet/ might be of great help as well. And i'll edit my post to add more comments.

Comment: Updated now, feel free to ask questions. I might messed up with terminology, but i hope main idea is still clear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each `ENSGID` corresponds to a unique pair of a and b values, I suggest:

1. Assign `cluster$Genes` to a variable (in other words, make a copy of it that is outside of the `cluster` data-frame). For example, `new_cluster_genes <- cluster$Genes`
2. Manipulate `new_cluster_genes` so that each row has a single `ENSGID`. Add a column header called `ENSGID`.
3. Merge `new_cluster_genes` with the expression data-frame, using `ENSGID` as the common ID. Assign the resulting data-frame to a variable: for example, `merged_genes`.
4. Calculate the min, max and mean values of a and b (separately) for each row:

   ```
   library(dplyr) 
   merged_genes %>% 
   mutate(min.a = min(a),
          max.a = max(a), 
          mean.a = mean(a), 
          min.b = min(b), 
          max.b = max(b), 
          mean.b = mean(b)) -> merged_genes
   ```
5. Create 6 new columns and fill them with the (min.a, max.a, mean.a, min.b, max.b, mean.b) values:

   ```
   merged_genes %>% select(ENSGID, min.a:mean.b) -> merged_genes_subset
   ```

Manipulate the `cluster` data-frame so that each row has a single ENSGID. Add a column header called `ENSGID`. Merge `merged_genes_subset` with cluster, using `ENSGID` as the common ID.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, but wouldn't doing (2) make me lose the information of which IDs (i.e. ENSGID) are in each row of the `cluster$Genes`? I want the various calculations of `a` and `b` for all the IDs of each row, not separately. For example, in the last row, [min,max,mean](a / b) = [1,2,1.5](a) / [0,3,1.5](b)